# node js process on exit not work using forever

Tags: node.js

I want some work on process exiting.

But `process.on('exit')` is not working using express or socket.io or  mysql, etc.

```
process.on('exit', function() {
    console.log('Server exit.');
});
```

only this code is working.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var conn = mysql.createConnection();

conn.connect();

process.on('exit', function() {
    console.log('Server exit.');
});
```

this is not working.

Comment: Not working how?  What's the problem?

Comment: `process.on('exit')` event not work on server restarting(forever restaring) and exit.

Comment: "not work" is not a problem, it's a guess. What happens when? Can you explain what you do in which you expect on('exit') to do something?

Comment: I want just something work on server closing.

Comment: I'd recommend `pm2` over `forever` (which seems pretty badly maintained nowadays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because once you initialize `express()`, say (specifically: start the server), or create a MySQL connection, or do anything else that "lives in the background", node will not exit, so will not called you `.on('exit')`.

It will not exit because it has pending tasks. It's just like if you were to invoke `setInterval()`.

If you disconnect the MySQL connection, or stop the express server, it will then exit and invoke you handler.

Answer (score 4):

You can make it work by doing two simple things:

1. Instead of using the `exit` event, use the `SIGINT` event (instead of `process.on('exit',function(){/*stuff here*/});` use `process.on('SIGINT',function(){/*stuff here*/});`
2. When starting the forever script, instead of just doing `forever start your-script.js`, type `forever start your-script.js --killSignal=SIGINT`

this works for me, but my script doesn't use much mysql and doesn't use any express, so it might not work for you